# javascript urls in IE pinned site task list

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pinned-site

I'm attempting to set up Pinned Site features for my project. The trouble is that I'd like to have the tasks be javascript actions rather than loading a new page. The reason for this is that the site is designed to only ever work in a single window.

I tried adding the following META tag:

```
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Test Action;
        action-uri=javascript:ui('test',8);icon-uri=/img/icons/test.ico" />
```

However this causes the task to simply not appear. (Using a normal URL makes it show up just fine)

Is there any way to do this? The best I can think of is a hash and check for the `hashchange` event, but this doesn't work because it gets opened in a new tab of the window...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by using a hash. By setting the `action-uri` to something readable by JavaScript, the JS can then read it, process the instruction, and then clear the hash in preparation for the next task.

This has the advantage that it works even when the window isn't already open, since the JS will read the hash on the first load too.

The catch is to add `window-type=self` to the content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not supported, because action list is designed for launching an application, not for a navigation inside it.

If you really want implement it, you can open a new window, send a message to server via web sockets and let server to forward that message to application window also via web sockets. But this is very hacky approach and works only in IE10.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm actually going to answer my own question since I figured out a way that works.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out how to make that works. I didn't know about this feature. I didn't find it on MSND Lib. This is mentioned just on blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonbox/archive/2011/03/05/ie9-changes-to-jump-lists-some-good-and-some-great.aspx